# Spring Webflow Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response hasbeen committed

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webflow-2

I have and webapplication based in Spring Webflow and Primefaces, and sometimes when I execute the screen I get the IllegalStateException ... but is really weird since we are not making a call before render the screen to have this tipe of error... What else we need to look at to fix this error?

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/Project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:483)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse.sendRedirect(FirewalledResponse.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:91)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.sendRedirect(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:324)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.sendFlowExecutionRedirect(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:372)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handleFlowExecutionResult(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:339)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I keep running into this same issue as well.  Usually (*for me anyway*) this is due to something being added to the flow that is not `Serializable`.  You should get a more informative message by adding setting the log level to `DEBUG` for `org.springframework.web.servlet`.

Comment: @Forward You are welcome.  This is one of those problems I have _solved_ for myself 3 or 4 times.  Each time I immediately forget what I did...  So this answer serves to inform me the next time I run into this.

Comment: came across this just now and setting the log level to DEBUG for org.springframework.web.servlet worked.  Thanks!